# Checking if mysql user exists

Tags: mysql

How can I check if a user exists?

Im doing an installer for a mysql database, and I need to check if a user exits, if not create user, if yes delete user and create it again.

this so i can execute the script without worries.

thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're deleting the MySQL user anyways, then there's really no need to check if it exists first. MySQL won't throw any errors if there's nothing to delete:

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'username';
```

Comment: This will delete the user just from user table, if you take this approach, you've to delete also from mysql.columns_priv, mysql.db, mysql.tables_priv. Also this list of table may change in future MySQL versions.

Comment: Never, ever, delete a user this way. Use the `DROP USER` command.

Comment: What if we need check if a user exists so we can prompt whether the user should be deleted?

Answer (score 77):

MySQL stores user data in a table called `user` in a database named `mysql` (by default). The following query will return `1` if a user with the specified username exists, `0` otherwise.

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'username')
```

Comment: Why not just `SELECT count(*) FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'username'`. Anything `>1` means user exists

Comment: "Exists" is much more efficient than "count".

Comment: If you want to check for both `user` and `host`, run something like: `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'username' AND host = 'localhost')`

Answer (score 6):

As newer versions of MySQL allow this option:

```
DROP USER IF EXISTS 'username'@'host';
```

Comment: not supported in MySql 6

Answer (score 2):

When in need to check if a user exists **without deleting** it (for instance when just skipping some instructions instead of executing them in any case), one can use this (where `$USER` is the user to check):

```bash
if [ $(echo "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mysql.user WHERE user = '$USER'" | mysql | tail -n1) -gt 0 ]
then
  echo "User exists"
else
  echo "User doesn't exist"
fi
```

NB:

- `mysql` command requires extra args and/or configuration for authentication)
- `tail -n1` is used for removing the query result header

Answer (score 1):

MySQL lacks DROP USER IF EXISTS construct.

A good workaround is to grant a harmless privilege to the user before dropping it.  This
will create the user if it doesn't exist, so that it can be dropped safely, like so:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
DROP USER 'username'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

USAGE actually means no privilege.

Source: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19166

Comment: For posterity, this workaround no longer works. Quoting from another answer's comment: "This is no longer an option. :( The current version of MySQL no longer creates a new user for the GRANT statement. It was a "Feature" they added. ;)" For original reference, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3241918/656243

Answer (score 1):

This is how I was able to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit
set -o nounset

# Create credentials file
echo -e "[client]\nuser=root\npassword=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}" > ~/.my.cnf

# Create standard user and grant permissions
if ! echo "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'myuser';" | mysql | grep 1 &> /dev/null; then
    echo "Creating database user ..."
    echo "CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
          GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydatabase.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
          FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" | mysql
else
    echo "Database user already created. Continue ..."
fi
```

Change `myuser`, `mydatabase` and `mypassword` accordingly.

Comment: This doesn't work well if the username contains the digit 1. So this can causes pitfalls.

Comment: @Joachim just tested it with a user with a 1 in its username, and it works perfectly. Are you sure? Why should it not work for a user with a 1?

Comment: why `grep 1`? what if the `SELECT COUNT(*)` returns `2`?

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr if you `use mysql; describe user;` you will note that: `User | char(32) | PRI`. Because `user` is a primary key it implies that it is unique. Which means that an exact match `==` it is impossible to return more than 1.

Comment: It is actually a composite key. `User` column alone is not `PRI`. If you look closely, you will see that the primary key is a composite of `Host`+`User`. `Host    char(60)        NO      PRI` and `User    char(32)        NO      PRI`

Comment: That means if you have created a user that can access from local host as well as another IP, the count will be more than 1. On my development system, I have the `my_app_user` user setup to allow access from another IP as well (`CREATE USER 'my_app_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_pass'; CREATE USER 'my_app_user'@'192.168.1.52' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_pass';`). The result of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'my_app_user';` is `2`. which is correct and expected. Hope you understand now

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr great analysis. Indeed I missed that. My use case was to create a user if it doesn't exists in an entrypoint of a Docker image. So either that single user was created or not. It would be nice to modify this snippet to incorporate that.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.7 already includes [`DROP USER IF EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-user.html), but for older versions I use [`pt-show-grants --drop`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-show-grants.html#cmdoption-pt-show-grants-drop) from percona-toolkit and feed back the `DROP USER` part to mysql:

```
pt-show-grants --drop --only=$username | grep '^DROP USER' | mysql -v
```

If there are multiple username-hostname pairs this removes all of them.