# how to check user exists using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a query such as

```
def create_db_and_admin(self):
        mysql_server = mysql.connect(host=self.db_server, user="root", passwd="password")
        cursor = mysql_server.cursor()
try:
            create_new_db = f"CREATE DATABASE {self.db}"
            cursor.execute(create_new_db)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Cant create a db")
            print(e)
            sys.exit()
        try:
            create_new_admin_user = f"CREATE USER '{self.db_admusr}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '{self.db_adm_passwd}'"
except Exception as e:
            print("User already exists")
            print(e)
            ad_user_admin_rights = f"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON {self.db_name}.* TO '{self.db_admusr}'@'%'"
```

I want to check if the user exists then I will just pass grant option rather than creating the user. Can someone suggest some ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do this instead

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

and then grant permissions

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON {self.db_name}.* TO '{self.db_admusr}'@'%'
```

Your code will look something like

```
def create_db_and_admin(self):
    mysql_server = mysql.connect(host=self.db_server, user="root", passwd="password")
    cursor = mysql_server.cursor()
    try:
        create_new_db = f"CREATE DATABASE {self.db}"
        cursor.execute(create_new_db)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Cant create a db")
        print(e)
        sys.exit()
    create_new_admin_user = f"CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS '{self.db_admusr}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '{self.db_adm_passwd}'"
    ad_user_admin_rights = f"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON {self.db_name}.* TO '{self.db_admusr}'@'%'"
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that but the only issue is I am trying random password and even if the user exists, it generates password for that

Comment: Try this: `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'username')` (Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3049942/3033441)