# Combining DROP USER and DROP DATABASE with SELECT .. WHERE query?

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

I'd like to make a very simple thing, [replicate the functionality of mysql's interactive mysql_secure_installation script](https://superuser.com/questions/472013/how-to-secure-mysql-using-command-line). My question is that is there a simple, built-in way in MySQL to combine the output of a SELECT query with the input of a DROP user or DROP database script?

For example, if I'd like to drop all users with empty passwords. How could I do that with DROP USER statement? I know an obvious solution would be to run everything for example from a Python script,

1. run a query with `mysql -Bse "select..."`
2. parse the output with some program
3. construct the drop query
4. run it.

Is there an easy way to do it in a simple SQL query? I've seen some example here, but I wouldn't call it simple: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12097567/518169

Would you recommend making a combined query, or just to parse the output using for example Python or bash scripts/sed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build SQL dynamically, for example:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('DROP USER ', GROUP_CONCAT(QUOTE(User), '@', QUOTE(Host)))
INTO   @sql
FROM   mysql.user
WHERE  PASSWORD = ''
```

Then [prepare a statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) from it:

```sql
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql
```

Then execute that statement:

```sql
EXECUTE stmt
```

Finally, deallocate the prepared statement:

```sql
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is using `--skip-column-names` flag and piping the output of `SELECT CONCAT(..)` query back to another mysql session:

```
echo 'select concat("DROP USER ",user,"@\"",host,"\";") from mysql.user where User = "alex"' \
| mysql -uroot --skip-column-names \
| mysql -uroot
```

source https://stackoverflow.com/a/47902078/410939