# DROP USER IF EXISTS triggers syntax error in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a brand new mysql installation. I want to [delete a user only if exists](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-user.html) and I have only `root` user. I'm trying to run from shell:

```
DROP USER IF EXISTS foo;
```

or

```
DROP USER IF EXISTS 'foo'@'localhost';
```

But mysql returns this kind of messages:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS foo' at line 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598190/mysql-check-if-the-user-exists-and-drop-it) but does not explain why `IF EXISTS` statement does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Check if the user exists and drop it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598190/mysql-check-if-the-user-exists-and-drop-it)

Comment: What's the version of mysql you are running? The if exists option is available from v5.7.8 only.

Comment: @robsn That post does not explain why `IF EXISTS` statements do not work as mentioned in the official docs.

Comment: @Shadow probably you got the point, my version: `Server version: 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [your own link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-user.html):

> **As of MySQL 5.7.8**, the IF EXISTS clause can be used, which causes the
>   statement to produce a warning for each named account that does not
>   exist, rather than an error.

You can find out your server version with e.g.:

```
select @@version;
```

Comment: `5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1` that's the problem :( I believed I was working on last version. I'm sorry, not a great question...